# Send json from raspberry Pi4 to Laravel and view it

Tags: python, php, laravel

I need to send a JSON file from a raspberry (programmed in python) to Laravel. Looking on the internet I found this function for python:

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

but when I go to view the JSON file on Laravel nothing appears.

The code in python is this:

```
def readFile():
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/device.txt", "r") as file:
        for i in file:
            line, *lines = i.split()
            if line in mac_dict:
                mac_dict[line] += lines
            else:
                mac_dict[line] = lines
    print(mac_dict)
    print("\n")

    json_obj = json.dumps(mac_dict, indent=4)
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/mac_addr.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(json_obj)

    r = requests.get(ip, data=json_obj, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
```

I use this function to read a txt file (containing the various Bluetooth MAC addresses and their respective RSSI values) and then transform it into JSON. Now I wanted to understand how to send it to Laravel and display something

The function in Laravel is this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DictionaryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('backend.auth.user.dictionary');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return $request;
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The route in laravel is in the api.php:

```
Route::get('dictionary', [DictionaryController::class, 'store'])->name('dictionary');
```

I hope to have explained well and that someone can help me, I am stuck for several days on this.
I also need to know how to use php/blade on Laravel to display the JSON file (if it is possible)

Thanks in advance

Comment: A Raspberry Pi is a piece of hardware, Laravel is a PHP framework, so your question is not making a lot of sense. What are you trying to achieve here? Doing an HTTP post from your python script to PHP?

Comment: Yes, I need to send via HTTP GET or POST request a Json file that is contained in my Raspberry to Laravel framework

Comment: I see no attempt in your Python code to open an HTTP request. This is pretty basic functionality that you should be able to find plenty of example on.

Comment: I use the requests.post method to send my file to Laravel

Answer (score 0):

> I use this function to read a txt file (containing the various Bluetooth MAC addresses and their respective RSSI values) and then transform it into JSON. Now I wanted to understand how to send it to Laravel and display something

I assume that your writing JSON via Python has worked. So, what you're asking is how Laravel can see JSON file.

```
class DictionaryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $json = file_get_contents('/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/mac_addr.json');
        return response()->json($json);
    }

    ...
```

Route :

```
Route::get('dictionary', [DictionaryController::class, 'index'])->name('dictionary.index');
```

Or if you want to work with template, you can use:

```
class DictionaryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $json = '/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/Bluetooth/mac_addr.json';
        $data['macs'] = json_encode($json, true);

        return view('backend.auth.user.dictionary', $data);
    }

    ...
```

And then you can process it however you want on the Blade.

Comment: With your first solution I have this in my view: 

"\/home\/pi\/Desktop\/Progetti SIoTD\/Bluetooth\/mac_addr.json"

And if I want to work with the JSON file, how can I do?

Comment: What is it? Btw, can you post `mac_addr.json` too?

Comment: You mean update and store?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forget to add `file_get_contents`. Please check my update